# Replace nth occurrence javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

in this example string `'1,2,3,4,5'` I am trying to capture and replace the 3rd occurence of the comma `,` character

this code here

```
'1,2,3,4,5'.match(/(?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*(,)/)
```

matches `1,2,3` and the comma im looking for
but not sure how to replace just the comma

```
'1,2,3,4,5'.replace(/(?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*(,)/, "$")
```

replaces everything before `4` giving `$4,5`

i just want a string result like `1,2,3$4,5` for example

I have achieved this task in two different ways, with array split and slice and with a String#replace that takes a callback

```
//splice
let parts = [];
let str = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
let formatted = ((parts = str.split(",")).slice(0,3)).join("-") + ' ' + parts.slice(3).join(":")
​
//callback
let str = "1,2,3,4,5"; 
str.replace(/,/g, (() => {
  let count = 0;
  return (match, position) => {
    count += 1;
    if(count == 3) return ' ';
    else if(count < 3) return '-';
    else return ':';        
  });
})())
```

Is this even possible with a plain `String#replace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing group and replace by first capturing group

```
.replace(/((?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/g, "$1:");
          ^                  ^
```

The captured group will capture the matched string except the third comma which is `$1` in the replacement string.

```js
console.log('1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5'.replace(/((?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/g, "$1:"));
```